# Json : Save Images into CoreData in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, sendasynchronousrequest

I’m now stuck little bit. First, my code is as follows,

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var eTitles : [String] = []
var jTitles : [String] = []
var pCategories : [String] = []
var imgPaths : [String] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/post.php")
    let allData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let allJsonData : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(allData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)

    if let json = allJsonData as? Array<AnyObject>{

        //println(json)

        for index in 0...json.count-1{

            let post : AnyObject? = json[index]

            //println(post)
            let collection = post! as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            //println(collection)

            //println(collection["Eng_Title"])


            var eTitle : AnyObject?  = collection["Eng_Title"]
            var jTitle : AnyObject? = collection["Jam_Title"]
            var pCategory : AnyObject? = collection["Category"]
            var imgPath : AnyObject? = collection["Category_Img"]



            eTitles.append(eTitle as String)
            jTitles.append(jTitle as String)
            pCategories.append(pCategory as String)
            imgPaths.append(imgPath as String)

        }

    }



    println(eTitles)
    println(jTitles)
    println(pCategories)
    println(imgPaths)

    for var i = 0; i < pCategories.count; i++
    {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!
        let category = Category(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        category.title = pCategories[i]
        category.path = fetchImg(imgPaths[i])
        appDelegate.saveContext()


        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Post", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!
        let post = Post(entity: en, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        post.jtitle = jTitles[i]
        post.etitle = eTitles[i]
        post.category = category
        appDelegate.saveContext()

    }

}



func fetchImg(path : String) -> String{

    var urlWebView = NSURL(string: path)!
    println(urlWebView)
    var requestWebView = NSURLRequest(URL: urlWebView)
    var saveP : String = ""


    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(requestWebView, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {

        response, data, error in

        if error != nil {

            println("There was an error")
          } 
         else {

           // let musicFile = (data: data)

            var documentsDirectory:String?
            var paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

            if paths.count > 0 {
                documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String
                var savePath = documentsDirectory! + "/" + NSUUID().UUIDString + ".jpg"

                println(savePath)
                saveP = savePath

                NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(savePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)


            }

        }

    })

   return saveP
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }


}
```

Everytime I run this app, it stops at this line :

> NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(requestWebView, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {

(What I’m trying to do here is to parse Json data and put it into array, and then save it into CoreData. The problem is **fetchImg()** function.
I’m trying to pass paths, which come from Json data, to this function, and the function fetch real images from web, create a path and save the data onto device, and return the path to which images actually are saved.)

Any advice?

Sorry for my poor Eng explanation!!!

Thanks!

Comment: If I had to guess, which any answers will be given the lack of information.  I'd guess that the URL being passed in isn't a valid URL, probably because it's partial and/or relative.  What is the URL?  What is the error when it crashes?  And, fwiw, this isn't saving the images in CoreData, which is actually a good thing.

Comment: Also, sendAsyncronousRequest sends a request, well.... Asyncronously, which means the result isn't available at the return statement, so this routine will always return an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! The URL must be valid...something like: "http://localhost:8888/img/20140501_041438713_iOS.jpg"

Comment: Before the above URL, there is "http://"

Comment: There is no error message on console, just (lldb)

Comment: So should I use syncronousRequest?